# Sorting for custom fields in models in django admin

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-admin

I want to  have sorting functionality for custom model field in django admin.

The code is similar to

```
class MyModel(models.Model):

    first_name = models.CharField()
    last_name = models.CharField()

    def most_recent_mailing_date(self):
        """ Return the most recent mailing date """
        mailingHistories = self.mailinghistory_set.all()

        if len(mailingHistories) != 0:
            today = datetime.date.today()
            mostRecentHistory = None
            diff = -1

            for mailingHistory in mailingHistories:

                if mailingHistory.mailing_date < today and (diff == -1 or (today - mailingHistory.mailing_date) < diff):

                    mostRecentHistory = mailingHistory
                    diff = today - mostRecentHistory.mailing_date

            if mostRecentHistory is None:
                return "No Mailing History"
            else:
                return mostRecentHistory.mailing_date
        else:
            return "No Mailing History"


    most_recent_mailing_date.admin_order_field = 'self.most_recent_mailing_date'
```

The field I want to order is most_recent_mailing_date.
It is a custom field.
Is it possible?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Since Django 2.1 you can use an expression to order by custom/non-DB fields in admin_order_by, but I don't understand how to do it! Not sure if this comment will make this more relevant, as Django 2+ only runs on Python 3+...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that's possible. From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display):

> You have four possible values that can be used in list_display:
>
> ....
>
> A string representing an attribute on the model. This behaves almost
>   the same as the callable, but self in this context is the model
>   instance. Here’s a full model example:

```
from django.db import models from django.contrib import admin

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    birthday = models.DateField()

    def decade_born_in(self):
        return self.birthday.strftime('%Y')[:3] + "0's"
    decade_born_in.short_description = 'Birth decade'

class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'decade_born_in')
```

Thus, your field is the fourth option. However:

> A few special cases to note about list_display:
>
> ...
>
> Usually, elements of list_display that aren’t actual database fields
>   can’t be used in sorting (because Django does all the sorting at the
>   database level).
>
> ...(goes on to describe exception that doesn't apply here).

### Thus, you can only sort on actual database fields.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use Django's `order_by` since it is applied at the database level. The database does not know anything about your python methods and properties.

However, You can do the ordering in Python

```
objects = MyModel.objects.all()
sorted(objects, key=lambda k: k.most_recent_mailing_date())
```

If you want reverse ordering,

```
objects = MyModel.objects.all()
sorted(objects, key=lambda k: k.most_recent_mailing_date(), reverse=True)
```

**Advice**

- I think you should be consistent on your return type. If there are no mailing history, you can return some old date instead of returning a string.
- I think you should consider using the @property decorator on your most_recent_mailing_date() so you can simply refer to it as `instance.most_recent_mailing_date`. This will make it somehow consistent on how you refer to your actual model fields.